# How to fix: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '&'

Tags: javascript

How to fix: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '&'

```html
'use strict';
var _$_d9ef = [&quot;Activated script&quot;, &quot;info&quot;, &quot;Crop&quot;, &quot;prototype&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;.&quot;, &quot;split&quot;, &quot;substring&quot;, &quot;display&quot;, &quot;css&quot;, &quot;#free_play_digits&quot;, &quot;none&quot;, &quot;#free_play_result&quot;, &quot;random&quot;, &quot;floor&quot;, &quot;html&quot;, &quot;#multiplier_first_digit&quot;, &quot;#multiplier_second_digit&quot;, &quot;#multiplier_third_digit&quot;, &quot;#multiplier_fourth_digit&quot;, &quot;#multiplier_fifth_digit&quot;, &quot;#free_play_first_digit&quot;, &quot;#free_play_second_digit&quot;, &quot;#free_play_third_digit&quot;, &quot;#free_play_fourth_digit&quot;, &quot;#free_play_fifth_digit&quot;, &quot; &quot;, &quot;innerHTML&quot;, &quot;.br_0_0_5_0&quot;, &quot;#winnings&quot;, 
&quot;#balance&quot;, &quot;balance&quot;];
console[$_d9ef[1]]($d9ef[0]);
Number[$d9ef[3]][$_d9ef[2]] = function(mmCoreSplitViewBlock) {
  var s = this + $_d9ef[4];
  var a = s[$d9ef[6]]($_d9ef[5]);
  a[1] = a[1] || $_d9ef[4];
  return parseFloat(a[0] + _$_d9ef[5] + a[1][$_d9ef[7]](0, mmCoreSplitViewBlock));
};
var i = true;
var t = 0;
var zaderjka = 1000;
setInterval(function() {
  if ($($_d9ef[10])[$d9ef[9]]($_d9ef[8]) != _$_d9ef[11]) {
    t++;
    if (zaderjka &gt; t &amp;&amp; $($_d9ef[12])[$d9ef[9]]($_d9ef[8]) == _$_d9ef[11]) {
      $($_d9ef[16])[$d9ef[15]](Math[$d9ef[14]](Math[$d9ef[13]]() * 10));
      $($d9ef[17])[$d9ef[15]](Math[$d9ef[14]](Math[$d9ef[13]]() * 10));
      $($d9ef[18])[$d9ef[15]](Math[$d9ef[14]](Math[$d9ef[13]]() * 10));
      $($d9ef[19])[$d9ef[15]](Math[$d9ef[14]](Math[$d9ef[13]]() * 10));
      $($d9ef[20])[$d9ef[15]](Math[$d9ef[14]](Math[$_d9ef[13]]() * 10));
    } else
```

Comment: `&quot;` isn't valid javascript - however you got that "code", you need to do it differently - or, search and replace `&quot;` with `"`, `&gt;` with `>` and `&amp;` with `&` and  in your favourite editor

Comment: yes i can replace by what please ?

Comment: You need to change all the character codes like `&quot;` or `&gt;` with their actual characters. You can find tables of character codes and their actual characters online, e.g. https://www.rapidtables.com/web/html/html-codes.html

Comment: I Have a new error the final error i don't know why https://prnt.sc/16efthr

Comment: thank you jayce and jaromanda, and you have idea for fix this final error pls ?

Comment: If you have a new question, post a new question. And please leave out stuff like "urgent". Your question is not more urgent than anyone else's is.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick way to parse it out into readable code.

```js
 document.querySelector('[data-outgoing]').innerHTML = document.querySelector('[data-incoming]').innerHTML;
```

```css
[data-incoming]{
height:0;
opacity:0;
overflow:hidden;
}

[data-outgoing]{
padding:5px;
background;#f0f0f0;
 font-family: monospace;
    white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div data-incoming>
  'use strict';
var _$_d9ef = [&quot;Activated script&quot;, &quot;info&quot;, &quot;Crop&quot;, &quot;prototype&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;.&quot;, &quot;split&quot;, &quot;substring&quot;, &quot;display&quot;, &quot;css&quot;, &quot;#free_play_digits&quot;, &quot;none&quot;, &quot;#free_play_result&quot;, &quot;random&quot;, &quot;floor&quot;, &quot;html&quot;, &quot;#multiplier_first_digit&quot;, &quot;#multiplier_second_digit&quot;, &quot;#multiplier_third_digit&quot;, &quot;#multiplier_fourth_digit&quot;, &quot;#multiplier_fifth_digit&quot;, &quot;#free_play_first_digit&quot;, &quot;#free_play_second_digit&quot;, &quot;#free_play_third_digit&quot;, &quot;#free_play_fourth_digit&quot;, &quot;#free_play_fifth_digit&quot;, &quot; &quot;, &quot;innerHTML&quot;, &quot;.br_0_0_5_0&quot;, &quot;#winnings&quot;, 
&quot;#balance&quot;, &quot;balance&quot;];
console[$_d9ef[1]]($d9ef[0]);
Number[$d9ef[3]][$_d9ef[2]] = function(mmCoreSplitViewBlock) {
  var s = this + $_d9ef[4];
  var a = s[$d9ef[6]]($_d9ef[5]);
  a[1] = a[1] || $_d9ef[4];
  return parseFloat(a[0] + _$_d9ef[5] + a[1][$_d9ef[7]](0, mmCoreSplitViewBlock));
};
var i = true;
var t = 0;
var zaderjka = 1000;
setInterval(function() {
  if ($($_d9ef[10])[$d9ef[9]]($_d9ef[8]) != _$_d9ef[11]) {
    t++;
    if (zaderjka &gt; t &amp;&amp; $($_d9ef[12])[$d9ef[9]]($_d9ef[8]) == _$_d9ef[11]) {
      $($_d9ef[16])[$d9ef[15]](Math[$d9ef[14]](Math[$d9ef[13]]() * 10));
      $($d9ef[17])[$d9ef[15]](Math[$d9ef[14]](Math[$d9ef[13]]() * 10));
      $($d9ef[18])[$d9ef[15]](Math[$d9ef[14]](Math[$d9ef[13]]() * 10));
      $($d9ef[19])[$d9ef[15]](Math[$d9ef[14]](Math[$d9ef[13]]() * 10));
      $($d9ef[20])[$d9ef[15]](Math[$d9ef[14]](Math[$_d9ef[13]]() * 10));
    } else 
</div>

<div data-outgoing>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing the code through an HTML parser will change all the HTML character Entities to the characters they represent. Provided you backslash escape any tick characters and change any end script tags to `<\/script>` by backslash escaping the forward slash, the following example should show source in the usual characters, without executing any JavaScript code in the source:

```js
"use strict";

let source= 
// paste code with character entities after the tick:
`
'use strict';
var _$_d9ef = [&quot;Activated script&quot;, &quot;info&quot;, &quot;Crop&quot;, &quot;prototype&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;.&quot;, &quot;split&quot;, &quot;substring&quot;, &quot;display&quot;, &quot;css&quot;, &quot;#free_play_digits&quot;, &quot;none&quot;, &quot;#free_play_result&quot;, &quot;random&quot;, &quot;floor&quot;, &quot;html&quot;, &quot;#multiplier_first_digit&quot;, &quot;#multiplier_second_digit&quot;, &quot;#multiplier_third_digit&quot;, &quot;#multiplier_fourth_digit&quot;, &quot;#multiplier_fifth_digit&quot;, &quot;#free_play_first_digit&quot;, &quot;#free_play_second_digit&quot;, &quot;#free_play_third_digit&quot;, &quot;#free_play_fourth_digit&quot;, &quot;#free_play_fifth_digit&quot;, &quot; &quot;, &quot;innerHTML&quot;, &quot;.br_0_0_5_0&quot;, &quot;#winnings&quot;, 
&quot;#balance&quot;, &quot;balance&quot;];
console[$_d9ef[1]]($d9ef[0]);
Number[$d9ef[3]][$_d9ef[2]] = function(mmCoreSplitViewBlock) {
  var s = this + $_d9ef[4];
  var a = s[$d9ef[6]]($_d9ef[5]);
  a[1] = a[1] || $_d9ef[4];
  return parseFloat(a[0] + _$_d9ef[5] + a[1][$_d9ef[7]](0, mmCoreSplitViewBlock));
};
var i = true;
var t = 0;
var zaderjka = 1000;
setInterval(function() {
  if ($($_d9ef[10])[$d9ef[9]]($_d9ef[8]) != _$_d9ef[11]) {
    t++;
    if (zaderjka &gt; t &amp;&amp; $($_d9ef[12])[$d9ef[9]]($_d9ef[8]) == _$_d9ef[11]) {
      $($_d9ef[16])[$d9ef[15]](Math[$d9ef[14]](Math[$d9ef[13]]() * 10));
      $($d9ef[17])[$d9ef[15]](Math[$d9ef[14]](Math[$d9ef[13]]() * 10));
      $($d9ef[18])[$d9ef[15]](Math[$d9ef[14]](Math[$d9ef[13]]() * 10));
      $($d9ef[19])[$d9ef[15]](Math[$d9ef[14]](Math[$d9ef[13]]() * 10));
      $($d9ef[20])[$d9ef[15]](Math[$d9ef[14]](Math[$_d9ef[13]]() * 10));
    } else 
    ... etc;
`  // end of pasted code
;
let div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = `<pre><code>${source}</code></pre>`
document.body.append( div);
```